# Get list of sensors in Android

Tags: android

Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge and time. I need to program an application that using the sensors can react to the environment. Then, the first activity that I want to do is check the available sensors in my cellphone. I executed the next code, but I have troubles when I wanna show the list using TextView. The method sensorList is not recognized

sslist= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sensorList);

```
package com.example.sensorproximity;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SensorManager sm;
    List<Sensor> ss;
    TextView proxText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sslist= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sensorList);
        sm=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        ss=sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

        for (Sensor s: ss){
            sslist.append("\n\n" +s.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
<TextView
    android:id=@+id/sensorList""
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Sensor List:" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</ScrollView>
```

What is the best way to carry out this simple task?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show your activity_main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your sslist is not define both local or global variable. Perhaps your `TextView proxText;` should be `TextView sslist;` 
or 
`sslist= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sensorList);` change to `TextView sslist= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sensorList);` and your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sensorList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Sensor List:" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have changed it, but sensorList continues without  appearing among the possible implementations of findViewById.

Comment: I can get the list of sensor when i run and compile your code and xml

Comment: I get an error when I try to run, the error says:  sensorList can not be resolved or is not a field. It's so weird that you can run. Thank you.

Comment: Great and thank you for the updated code. Now you should get the sensor list and dont forget to vote it is answer

Comment: Than you so much for your time and knowledge. I have gotten the sensors in my device :)